# Generate sequence of floats in a certain range

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I want to fill a `vector<float>` with values, starting from `a`, increasing by `inc`, up to and including `b`. So basically what e.g. `vec = 2:0.5:4` in Matlab would do - `vec` should now be `{ 2.0, 2.5, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 }`.

The best I could come up with is

```
vector<float> vec(10);
float increment = 0.5f;
std::generate(begin(vec), end(vec), [&increment]() {static float start = 2.0f; return start += increment ; });
```

But obviously it is incorrect as it starts at 2.5f, not 2.0f. And I would like to specify the parameters a bit easier or more concise.

I could imagine doing it in a dedicated class, but that would require quite some code.
Also I've looked at std::iota, but it can only increase by `+1`.

Any ideas on the best, concise approach? Using C++11 (and some parts of 14) welcome.

Edit: Of course I've also used a for-loop like:

```
    for (float i = -1.0f; i <= 1.0f; i += 0.05f) {
        vec.emplace_back(i);
    }
```

but it has the problem that it sometimes doesn't go up to the end value, as in this example, because of float impreciseness (or rather representation). Fixing that requires some code and I think there should be a more concise way?

Comment: What's wrong with just using a for loop?

Comment: What do you mean it *sometimes* doesn't go up to 4.0f? It's deterministic, regardless of whether it's imprecise. But 3.5f is exactly representable, so why do you expect imprecision? And if it is imprecise, whatever you're going to do to fix that can be done at least as easily for the loop as for any other method.

Comment: Sorry, I should've formulated that clearer. With _sometimes_ I meant it depends on the increment and the end value, if the final accumulated value ends up being `<=` or actually `>` your stop value.

Comment: It's a good idea to use an example that actually demonstrates the problem. Yours doesn't. Note that, if `end` != `start + n * increment` for some integer `n`, then you *shouldn't* generate `end` as part of the sequence.

Comment: Yea, I can agree with you. However, as somebody in an answer here mentioned, it seems to depend on the platform, compiler, optimization, .... So it is more of a general problem and I'm not sure an example would help.

Comment: The second part of your comment is interesting! Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: No, it doesn't depend ... not if all platforms use IEEE754 floating point. A platform that gets wrong results is buggy.

Comment: If you want to replicate the precision of something like Matlab in C++, consider http://www.mpfr.org/

Comment: @JimBalter: Ok, I found the example where it failed at the upper bound. I've updated my example! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could write your own variant of [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) that also accepts a stride argument.

```
template<typename ForwardIterator, typename T>
void strided_iota(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, T value, T stride)
{
    while(first != last) {
        *first++ = value;
        value += stride;
    }
}
```

In your example, you'd use it as

```
std::vector<float> vec(10);
strided_iota(std::begin(vec), std::next(std::begin(vec), 5), 2.0f, 0.5f);
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7bf41ec6cbcfe7ca)

Comment: Will this always terminate? I believe 0.1, amongst other numbers, isn't representable exactly in binary, so <= may be safer with float/double.

Comment: @PhilWright: If you refer to the `while(first != last)`, this is comparing iterators, not float values, so it should be fine, right? (and even if it was comparing floats, `<=` wouldn't help, as seen in my example)

Comment: @Ela782 Ah yes, they're iterators, not numbers, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you really need any fancy features for this.

```
void fill_vec(vector<float>& vec, float a, float inc, float b)
{
    for(float n = a; n <= b; n += inc)
      vec.push_back(n);
}
```

If you're worried about floating point precision missing the upper range, then you can add a small amount (often denoted by epsilon for this sort of thing):

```
float eps = 0.0000001f;
for(float n = a; n <= b + eps; n += inc)
```

If you include `<cfloat>`, you can use FLT_EPSILON which may vary between platforms to suit the implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is that you want to include all the float values, then loop on integers and do the necessary calculations to go back to the float value within the loop.

```
for (int i = 20; i <= 40; i += 5) {
        vec.emplace_back(i/10.0);
    }
```

Comment: You might run into issues with, say, an increment of 0.005.

Comment: @JonnyD  And if you do, you still follow the general approach.  Always loop on integers, and calculate the float value within the loop.

Comment: The approach will work, but the values have to be hard-coded.  That will make for a lot of repeated code when using it several times.

Comment: Nothing has to be hardcoded.  If you know your float range and increment, you can set up your integers and calculations accordingly.

Comment: Hmm good hint with the integer values! But I don't really want to have to do this calculation every time I write such a for loop.

Comment: @Ela782 - Well be prepared for loops that may run a different number of times, depending on compiler, compiler settings, optimizations, etc.

Comment: @Ela782 - If your loops consist of floating point values that can be exactly represented in binary, then the loop will run a determinisitic number of times.  However, if either your begin, end, or increment values do not have an exact representation, then be aware that the loop may run inconsistently depending on many things (again, compiler, optimizations, etc.).  In the latter case, you have no choice but to come up with integral looping values, by hook or by crook (if you want consistency in the number of times the loop performs).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a functor that works for both for `iota` and `generate`. Overload the function call and increment operator appropriately:

```
template <typename T>
class ArithmeticProgression
{
    T val;
    T inc;

public:

    ArithmeticProg(T val, T inc) : val(val), inc(inc) {}

    ArithmeticProg& operator++() noexcept(noexcept(val += inc))
    {
        val += inc;
        return *this;
    }

    T operator()() noexcept(noexcept(val += inc))
    {
        auto tmp = val;
        val += inc;
        return tmp;
    }

    operator T() const noexcept {return val;}
};

template <typename T, typename U>
ArProg<typename std::common_type<T, U>::type> makeArithmeticProg( T val, U inc )
{
    return {val, inc};
}
```

Usage:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<float> vec;
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(vec), 5, makeArithmeticProg(2.0f, 0.5f) );

    for (auto f : vec)
        std::cout << f << ", ";

    std::cout << '\n';

    std::iota( std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), makeArithmeticProg(2.5f, 0.3f) );

    for (auto f : vec)
        std::cout << f << ", ";
}
```

#### [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6f45cf3311860c26).

Comment: Nice solution. May I ask why you named it `ArProg` - is there some meaning behind it I can't figure out?

Comment: @Ela782 Arithmetic Progression.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

// functor
class generator_float
{
    float _start, _inc;
public:
    generator_float(float start, float inc): _start(start), _inc(inc) {};
    float operator()() {
        float tmp = _start;
        _start += _inc;
        return tmp;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<float> vec(10);
    std::generate(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), generator_float(2,0.5));
    for(auto&& elem: vec)
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```